# Asp Core Api Route that Accepts All Paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Trying to find somewhere that explains how to create a route that accepts all requests starting with a particular name. As well as retrieving information of that request. So an example of that would be creating a route of `test` that accepts all incoming get requests of that route.

Ideally, something that supports

```
[Route("test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    // so that all request that start with 'test' go through this method
    public IActionRequest Process() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

```
[Route("test/{*any}")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    // so that all request that start with 'test' go through this method
    public IActionResult Process()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new{
            a = 1,
        });
    }

}
```

**Approach 2:**

register a catch-all route :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:"routeAny",
        template:"test/{*any}",
        defaults: new{
            Controller = "Test",
            Action = "Process",
        }
    );
});
```

And remove the `[ApiController]` attribute because it requires a `[Route()]`:

```
[ApiController]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    // so that all request that start with 'test' go through this method
    public IActionResult Process()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new{
            a = 1,
        });
    }

}
```